# Generating duplicate responses within a MySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I am using the report writing functionality within an application to generate barcode product labels.

The report writing system allows me to use a MySQL SELECT statement to get the information I need from our database and present it to a Jasper Reports JRXML file that formats the report.

This works fine if I want to produce one barcode label for each product returned from the database by my SELECT statement.  However I want to produce fifty copies of each product label.

Easy enough if I had access to the code, but all I can change is the SQL statement.

Can anyone suggest a way in which I can get a MySQL SELECT statement to return 50 identical results for each record it finds in the products table?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmmmm... No way comes to mind, although I'm sure there is one (the mySQL gurus will sort it out). However, this would be nicer to do on app level. Are you 100% sure there is no native way of doing this in Jasper Reports, or the application itself?

Answer (score 1):

I just have an ugly solution, assuming you can modify the schema: create a dummy table containing 50 records and join it in your sql queries like this: select * from products, dummyWith50Records

I'm almost shameful to write something like that, but it should work ... Hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: I don't have access to the application, but creating a dummy table is possible.  There is a mechanism to pass parameters to the SQL statement so I had hoped to be able to specify the number of labels and embed it in the SQL statement.  However the dummy table will work so I'll go with that unless someone has any other ideas.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote here. I still don't see any better solution.

Comment: This isn't an ugly solution. Using an auxiliary table with nothing but numbers in it is a very convenient way of solving lots of query problems. See discussion here: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html

Answer (score 1):

A cross join against a on-the-fly table of dud information with as many rows as you want duplicates.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table t 
JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) dud 
WHERE t.field = 'condition'
```

In this case, I'm getting 5 duplicates of every qualifying row in `table`.

It's not pretty, but it works, and it doesn't require creating a *real* table.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to understand your problem... But it would be more helpful for me with an example...

I think I was doing the same thing in one of my application